# How many ways we can draw 2 similar cards of the same rank

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways we can draw 2 similar cards with the same face value from the deck of 36 cards?

Deck has 4 suits and 9 cards in each suit

Comment: Some of us on the site are not familiar with cards; can you please define "similar" and "rank"? I assume you mean draw 2 cards with the same face value for the moment.

Comment: Yes, exactly - 2 cards with a same face value

Comment: And a deck of $36$ cards?  That deck is not the [standard 52-card deck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck) so some additional clarification is necessary.  I assume that this is something like a standard german deck where there are $4$ suits, and nine cards in each suit?

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, 4 suits, 9 cards in each suit

Comment: Additionally, you will need to clarify what exactly you are wishing to count.  Are you considering order relevant so that something like $A\clubsuit, A\heartsuit$ is considered a different outcome than $A\heartsuit,A\clubsuit$?  Or are these considered to be the same since the set of cards in the hand are the same?

Comment: The task is order irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly there are 4 cards of 9 possible values in the deck.

Assuming the order of two cards being irrelevant the number in question is:
$$
9\binom42=54.
$$

If the order matters the number should be multiplied by $2!=2$.

Comment: Additional clarification needs to be made by the OP or your answer needs a qualifier stating that your answer assumes that order of cards is irrelevant

Comment: @JMoravitz I have started my answer with an assumption about the deck composition. This assumption seems to be correct.

Comment: the assumption about the deck *composition* is not what I was referring to.  The *currently unstated* assumption (*which was only just now clarified by the OP*) that the order of drawing the cards is irrelevant is what I was referring to.  In some problems it is common to consider $A\clubsuit,A\heartsuit$ to be a "*different*" result than $A\heartsuit,A\clubsuit$.  In the first scenario you drew a club first.  That is a decidedly different outcome than drawing a heart first in several games.  If the OP stated that order of cards mattered, then your answer would have been incorrect.

Comment: @JMoravitz I have expanded the answer to cover both scenario.